# No such instance field: 'bottomNavigationView'

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

I am using new released Bottom Navigation View from android support library - 25.0.0. And I am trying to setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener and nothing is happened. When I tried to debug the project, I see the error: "No such instance field: 'bottomNavigationView'", but my bottomNavigationView is initialized and the method "getMaxItemCount" works perfectly.

I realized that it is not only the "navigationListener" problem, but also onClickListener. Because this code:

```
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) viewHierarchy.findViewById(R.id.tender_bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicky-clicky", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

also provides the same error. 
I saw the same mistakes with the boolean values here on site, but the most common answer for this was "restart android studio/clean the project". I have done it. Do you have any thoughts on this?

May be there is no way to implement bottomNavigationView inside a fragment?

**EDIT**: I tried this code in activity class and it works! So why does he lose the field in the fragment? That is still a riddle to me.

[image: error]

**EDIT 2:** The whole fragment code.

```
public class NewTenderFragment extends Fragment {

   BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

   FragmentManager fragmentManager;
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View viewHierarchy = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_tender, container, false);
       bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) viewHierarchy.findViewById(R.id.tender_bottom_navigation);
       int t = bottomNavigationView.getMaxItemCount(); //this returns "5"
       bottomNavigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this returns such error
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicky-clicky", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
   return viewHierarchy;
 }
```

Comment: What is `viewHierarchy` object in your case?

Comment: Please add a code that we can replicate the problem with so we can try it out and identify the problem.

Comment: @UneXp, I updated the question.

Comment: @LisaSemyonova, also what do you mean "nothing is happened"? `onNavigationItemSelected()` method not called when tapping items? Try to restart Android Studio to prevent issue with debugger (No such field...), the code seems to be correct. I don't really think there are some limitations with Fragments here.

Comment: @UneXp, I mean that toast is not appearing and the method onNavigationItemSelected() not called. I'm really confused about it. So the application continues to work and that mistake shows herself only while debugging. I've already restarted it and cleaned the project. Also tried this code in activity class and everything was perfect.

Comment: @LisaSemyonova I've tried to add it in Fragment and `onNavigationItemSelected()` is called without any problems. I'm also curious what can be wrong here :)